# How do i tell SpringData/Hibernate that i want my Non Unique Result as a java collection?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

So im developing an app that has localization support, so my db has localizations.
I have this query (using @Query annotation):

```
select new com.fullstack.daos.projections.LocalizedTutorialDAO(t.id, t.created, t.createdBy, t.lastModified, t.lastModifiedBy, t.version, t.exclusive, (VALUE(l)).name, (VALUE(l)).description, tp) from tutorial t join t.localizations l join t.topics tp where (VALUE(l)).name like %:name% and (KEY(l)) = :lang
```

If i don't include the t.topics it works perfectly fine, but if i do, it gives me:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique result: 3
```

The thing is, thats supposed to happen, see the t.topics is a set of string representing an @ElementCollection. When i do the default findById it fetches it, why cant my projection in this case convert the so called "non unique result" to the Set it is supposed to be?

```
public class LocalizedTutorialDAO {

    private UUID id;
    private LocalDateTime created;
    private String createdBy;
    private LocalDateTime lastModified;
    private String lastModifiedBy;
    private int version;
    private String name, description;
    private Set<String> topics = new HashSet<>();

    public LocalizedTutorialDAO(UUID id, LocalDateTime created, String createdBy, LocalDateTime lastModified,
            String lastModifiedBy, int version, boolean exclusive, String name, String description, String topics) {
        super(id, created, createdBy, lastModified, lastModifiedBy, version);
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.topics = topics;
    }
}
```

Comment: if you can put the definition of  com.fullstack.daos.projections.LocalizedTutorialDAO 
we can have some clarity.  where exactly is the exception? while  trying to put collection into set?

Comment: I have added the projection. The entity itself is the projection with 2 more relations. The exception is the NonUniqueResult i show up there. Says 3 results which is supposed to do but in a Set<String>

Comment: Are you sure when it is getting thrown? Because i can see from documentation of hibernate that
public class NonUniqueResultException
extends PersistenceException
Thrown by the persistence provider when Query.getSingleResult() or TypedQuery.getSingleResult() is executed on a query and there is more than one result from the query. This exception will not cause the current transaction, if one is active, to be marked for rollback.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/NonUniqueResultException.html

Comment: Yes i throws the exception when i do a select that it thinks should have a unique result, even tho it shouldnt. If i run it in mysql workbench que query works. And if i fetch my entity using findById it executes a similar query but then it puts that same result into a set, when i do the query manually throws that exception

Comment: @Lucia i guess my question here is why/how to make it use a query.getResult instead of trying to get a single result, because thats just wrong. My entity and projection state that its a Set, an ElementCollection so i can not possibly be a single result

Comment: Can you add your complete interface method and full stacktrace here.
It is really difficult without that

Comment: ALso Entity definition